# How to solve such this recurrence to find out time complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity

There is this version of merge sort where the array is divided into n/3 and 2n/3 halves each time(instead of n/2 and n/2 originally).

The recurrence here would be:
**T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n**

Now the problem is, how to solve this to **get the time complexity** of this implementation?

Comment: are you now able to calculate the time complexity, by going through my answer??

Answer (score 1):

There is [Akra–Bazzi_method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) to calculate complexity for some more complex cases than Master Theorem is intended for.

In this example you'll get the same `Theta(NlogN)` as for equal parts (`p=1, T=Theta(n(1+Integral(n/n^2*dn))`)

Answer (score 0):

`T(n)` denotes the total time taken by the algorithm.

**We can calculate time complexity of this recurrence relation through recursion tree.**

```
T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n         -------  1
```

Root node of `T(n)` is `n`, Root node will be expanded into 2 parts:

```
T(n/3) and T(2n/3)
```

[image]

In next step we will find root node value of `T(n/3) and T(2n/3)`
To compute `T(n/3)` substitute `n/3` in place of n  in equation 1

```
T(n/3)=T(n/9)+T(2n/9)+n/3
```

To compute `T(2n/3)` substitute `2n/3` in place of n  in equation 1

```
T(2n/3)=T(2n/9)+T(4n/9)+2n/3
```

Root node of T(n/3) is n/3root node will be expanded into 2 parts:

T(n/9) and T(2n/9)

***Expand root node value till you will get individual elements i.e T(1)***

**Calculation of depth:**
For calculating depth, `n/(b^i)=1`

So we will get, `n/(3^i)` or `n/((3/2)^i)`
If `n=9` then `n/3=3`, `2n/3=6`
for next level `n/9=1`, `2n/9=2`,`4n/9=4`

Right part of recursion tree `n->2n/3->4n/9` this is the longest path that we will take to expand the root node
If we take left part of tree to expand the root node, we will use  `n/(3^i)` to find the depth of tree, to know where the tree will stop

So here we are using right part of tree,  `n/((3/2)^i)`

```
n=(3/2)^i

log n=log(3/2)^i

i=(logn base 3/2)
```

Now, calculating cost of each level

[image]

Since, cost of each level is same i.e. `n`

```
T(n) = cost of level * depth
T(n) = n * i
```

> **T(n) = n(logn base 3/2)**

Or we can calculate using `T(n)=n+n+n..... i times` i.e `T(n) = n * i`

You can even find time complexity using [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method)